# How to save array in MySQL using Servlet?

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, servlets

I have an array like

```
[ BARIUM SWALLOW UPPER GI ,  600.0 ,  600.0 ,  BONE SCAN ,  1250.0 ,  1250.0 ,  BARIUM SWALLOW ,  850.0 ,  850.0 ]
```

Here I have to save the first 3 values in 1 row and next 3 in next row based on array size and this array is not fixed it may increases or decreases.

I have tried:

```
String actions= req.getParameter("tvalues");

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(",");
final String[] result = pattern.split(actions);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
List<String> testinfo = Arrays.asList(actions.split(","));

for (j=0;j<testinfo.size();j++) {
    System.out.println(testinfo.get(j));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we have the list object ,iterate it for each iteration it will get three parameter name ,no,no1 ,if you send these parameter to the writeToDb function .in that function it will update to the database ..

```
    list = Arrays.asList(str.split(","));  
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i += 3) {

        String name = list.get(i);
        String no = list.get(i + 1);
        String no1 = list.get(i + 2);
        System.out.println(name + no + no1);
        writeToDb(name, no, no1);
     }
```

create a wirteToDb function

```
public static void writeToDb(String name, String no, String no1) {

 //connect to database
    String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER"
            + "(USERNAME, no, no1) VALUES" + "(?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection
            .prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
    preparedStatement.setString(2, no);
    preparedStatement.setString(3, no1);
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

}

   }
```

Comment: In insert query: you are giving 4 fields but 3 values, is this a syntax error or am I missing something here?